# Using Entity Framework is there a way to use on key for one table and another key for a different table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have 3 tables in my SQL Server database `Insured`, `Quote` and `Producer`.

`Insured` and `Quote` share an `insuredID` and `Insured` and `Producer` share a `producerID` column. I tried to do a one to many relationship to get both keys to work but getting that `InsuredID` doesn't exist which wasn't an error before.

```
public class Insured
{
    public string InsuredID { get; set; }
    public string ProducerID { get; set; }
    public string NamedInsured { get; set; }
    public string Address1 {get; set;} 
}

public class Quote
{
    [Key]
    public string PolicyID { get; set; }
}

public class Producer
{
    [Key]
    public string ProducerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Insured>()
      .HasOne<Producer>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.ProducerID);
}
```

The error I get:

> SqlException: Invalid column name 'InsuredID'.
> Invalid column name 'InsuredID'.

Comment: In your code shown `Quote` has no column `InsuredID`, that is probably what is wrong with your model and what EF is stating. Once you fix that relationship you should then also include it in the `OnModelCreating` method.

Comment: What is the table DDL?  Are you generating the database from the model or generating the model from the database?

Comment: I added InsuredID in Quote and changed OnModelCreating to  builder.Entity<Insured>().HasKey(i => new
            {
                i.InsuredID,
                i.ProducerID
            });
but now I get the same error except Invalid column name 'InsuredID1' now

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue:
Just needed to add

```
[ForeignKey("ProducerID")]
        public ICollection<Producer> Producer { get; set; }
```

for the insured class